# How to insert filtered list in table and add additional row of naming for each columns

Tags: html, django

> I have a list of filtered value from `SQL` :

> in **views.py**

```
name_list=list(AB.objects.filter(name__in=xyz).values_list('name', 'surname', 'sector','industry', 'country','city'))
```

> in **template.html**:

```
<ul><li>{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %} {{ name }} </li></ul>
<ul><li>{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %} {{surname}} </li></ul>
<ul><li>{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %} {{sector}} </li></ul>
<ul><li>{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %} {{industry}} </li></ul>
<ul><li>{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %} {{country}} </li></ul>
<ul><li>{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %} {{city}} </li></ul>
```

Output of it is :

```
Alex   Klein       Machinery    Aerospace  USA      Kansas
Lia    Michelle    Healthcare   Drugs      Ireland  Dublin
```

I want to add names to each columns such as Name, Surname, Sector, Industry, Country, City and insert them in table. I made `ul` and `li`  as I di not know how to insert them in table

Desired output is table the following way :

```
Name   Surname     Sector       Industry   Country  City

Alex   Klein       Machinery    Aerospace  USA      Kansas
Lia    Michelle    Healthcare   Drugs      Ireland  Dublin
```

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you write the word `for` you are starting a loop. Try this:

```
{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %}
<ul><li> {{name}} </li></ul>
<ul><li> {{surname}} </li></ul>
<ul><li> {{sector}} </li></ul>
<ul><li> {{industry}} </li></ul>
<ul><li> {{country}} </li></ul>
<ul><li> {{city}} </li></ul>
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**

To render it as a table as requested in the comments:

```
<table>
<tbody>
{% for name, surname,sector,industry,country,city in name_list %}
<tr>
<td>{{name}}</td>
<td>{{surname}}</td>
<td>{{sector}}</td>
<td>{{industry}}</td>
<td>{{country}}</td>
<td>{{city}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How to add row of names : Name   Surname     Sector       Industry   Country  City? And how to insert in bootstrap table  <table></ table>

Comment: Your code does not show table. It is plain tex rather than html table

Comment: @Nina I added a table version to the answer, check it out